# How to increase time of tool tip of a datagrid column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tooltip

This is what I am doing right now:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ActionTaken}" Header="Action Taken" Width="150">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=ActionTaken}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952965/change-the-tooltip-initialshowdelay-property-globally). Should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to override the default value. Use this code only once (may be in the window init function).

```
 ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty.OverrideMetadata(
 typeof(DependencyObject), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(2000));
```

the value 2000 is in milliseconds. change it to what you like.