# UWP InitialShowDelay on ToolTipService

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, tooltip

I'm working on an UWP application and I have buttons on it. I added a simply ToolTipService:

[image: Gui]

[image: XAML]

But when I hover the mouse on the button, the tooltip takes almost 2 seconds for being show, and I'd like this to be instant. I looked for solutions, but all I find is about WPF and these solutions DON'T WORK. For example:

[Change the ToolTip InitialShowDelay Property Globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952965/change-the-tooltip-initialshowdelay-property-globally)

This doesn't work,

Than You!

ToolTip Class: 
[image]

Comment: This is by design and I don't think it can be changed.

Comment: WPF allows you to change this on XAML, i don't get why you can't in UWP, otherwhise, is there a solution in C#?

Comment: Why don't you just implement a user control that handles onPointerEntered() to show a fly-out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can´t be done the way I proposed, so as @MoDu mentioned, the best way is to show/hide a control handling onPointerEntered() event