# XAML Information Icon opens TeachingTip

Tags: windows, xaml, icons, tooltip, winui-3

How can I make in XAML WinUI 3 a circled "i" which on hover opens a TeachingTip? Like in the photo:

[image]

```
<TeachingTip Title="Title" Subtitle="Subtitle" Target="{x:Bind InformationIcon}"/>
```

Attempts:

1. I used `<FontIcon>` inside `<Border>`, but they do not have click events so I can't open the tip in code-behind.
2. If I use a `<Button>` with the icon then I can open the tip. But it has hover animation and is not a circle, and all I want is a static "i" encircled.

Comment: Why don't you use the regular Tooltip class, something like that https://pastebin.com/raw/u2staU72

Comment: That almost solves my question. The problem is Tooltip shows with delay and I cannot find the property `ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="1000"` to change that. Maybe it was removed.

Comment: It was not "removed", it just doesn't exist on WinUI3 (it's not a port of WPF) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031168/uwp-initialshowdelay-on-tooltipservice https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2262

Comment: Since no new answers appear, you can write this alternative with the normal Tooltip in an answer and I will check. It does almost all the things I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard tooltip, something like that:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Tags (optional)" />
    <TextBlock
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="20"
        Text="" ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <Border Margin="-10" Background="Black">
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="10"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="Tags are not visible account-wide&#10;Do not include sensitive data."
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Border>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

However the tooltip has less features than the WPF one, so there's no way to configure delays.